# Economic Linux PCIE Hardware

Tags: pcie

I need a more information to start for hands-on on PCIE Drivers:

Actually I want to practice PCIE driver from scratch with Linux Network/Storage/USB/Audio/Video driver. The missing point is hardware. Can you kindly help me by listing all hardware required for the same.This majorly I am requiring :

1. Peripheral IC/Boards.
2. Main board.
3. Supportive hardware.
4. Debugging hardware.
5. Guiding material to do handson.

For above, I need

1. Product weblinks.
2. Selling agencies weblinks.
3. Guiding material weblinks.

Regards.
Ankur

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get started is to buy an FPGA. Then you can program in some simple registers and an adder and practice moving data to and from those registers. Here is the [Xilinx cost optimized page](https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/cost-optimized-design.html).

If you can find a tutorial based on one of those boards then buy the card that goes with it. The PCIe cards are expensive, but you can buy a [$200 USB based card](https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/1-pnziih.html) and breakout the PCIe pins to the GPIO.

I recommend that start with a USB/COMM port driver first and get lots of practice with pointers and registers. Moving from that to PCIe will not be a big jump.